# media tool install instead of a reset on laptop

Tags: installation

just wondering if it is a good idea to fresh install? I would rather do this than reset on laptop.
this is because reset formats and does some config n bloatware, fresh install is core win 10, will drivers from windows be okay on modern laptop?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a Fresh Install with Windows (use the Windows ISO from the Media Creation Link) and then add the drivers you need. Be really careful to get ALL drivers.

You can do a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Nothing. This is almost the same as the above.

You can do a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep Data only. This removes Software Apps and you must reinstall these. But your data and User Profile (with its configs) will remain. This is often a good option.

I have found very little "bloatware" in the Lenovo machines we use, but if you have a lot, back up and do a Fresh Install.

You really do have some practical options here, especially if your machine is generally working well.

I have left out Vendor Reset as you are not keen on that. I use Vendor USB Recovery keys and find that to be very beneficial.